Generate SHA-256 HMAC in Base64 in Google AppScript
I would like to generate a base64 HMAC Authentication Code in Google Appscript.
This website - provides the exact solution:
https://www.devglan.com/online-tools/hmac-sha256-online
I just somehow cant get it working natively in Google Appscript.
This is what I have at the moment - but its not giving me the right key:
function HMAC() {

var urlParam = "message";
var APIkey = 'secret';

  var hash = Utilities.computeHmacSha256Signature(urlParam, APIkey).reduce(function(str,chr){
    chr = (chr < 0 ? chr + 256 : chr).toString(16);
    return str + (chr.length==1?'0':'') + chr;
  },'');;

  Logger.log(Utilities.base64Encode(hash));
}


function HMAC() {
 var urlParam = "message";
 var APIkey = 'secret';

 // Compute HMAC-SHA256 hash
 var hash = Utilities.computeHmacSha256Signature(urlParam, APIkey,Utilities.Charset.UTF_8);

 // Convert byte array to Base64
 var base64Hash = Utilities.base64Encode(hash);

 // Log the Base64 encoded HMAC
 Logger.log(base64Hash);

 return base64Hash;
}


Byte Conversion: Utilities.computeHmacSha256Signature is given the
message and the secret key. Here, Utilities.Charset.UTF_8 ensures
that the string is encoded properly before the hash computation.

Base64 Encoding: Instead of converting the byte array to a
hexadecimal string first, you directly encode it into Base64. This
is done using Utilities.base64Encode, which correctly handles the
byte array.



Thanks so much! Works perfectly. I really dont understand what's happening here, but it works...

Use Utilities.computeHmacSha256Signature() and Utilities.base64Encode(), like this:
/** 
* @customfunction
*/
function testHmac(value = 'message', key = 'secret') {
  const signature = getHmacSignatureBase64_(value, key);
  return signature;
}


/** 
* Calculates HMAC-SHA256 and encodes it in Base64.
*
* @param {String[]} value The data to sign.
* @param {String[]} key The key to use.
* @return {String[]} Base64 encoded signature.
*/
function getHmacSignatureBase64_(value, key) {
  const hash = Utilities.computeHmacSha256Signature(value, key);
  const base64 = Utilities.base64Encode(hash);
  return base64;
}

To test the function, put this formula in a spreadsheet cell:
=testHmac()

The result will match what you get at devglan.
To test with other values and keys, put those values and keys in spreadsheet cells, and refer to those values like this:
=testHmac(A1, B1)

See Utilities.computeHmacSha256Signature() and Utilities.base64Encode.
